# How to troubleshoot and solve lambda function issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services

```js
import sys
import botocore
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    rds = boto3.client('rds')
    lambdaFunc = boto3.client('lambda')
    print 'Trying to get Environment variable'
    try:
        funcResponse = lambdaFunc.get_function_configuration(
            FunctionName='RDSInstanceStart'
        )
        #print (funcResponse)
        DBinstance = funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']['DBInstanceName']
        print 'Starting RDS service for DBInstance : ' + DBinstance
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)    
    try:
        response = rds.start_db_instance(
            DBInstanceIdentifier=DBinstance
        )
        print 'Success :: ' 
        return response
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)    
    return
    {
        'message' : "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output"
    }
```

I have a running rds instance. Every day I start and stop my RDS instance(db.t2.micro (MSSQL Server)) of AWS using a lambda expression. It was working fine previously but unexpectedly today I faced the issue.
Where my rds instance is not started automatically by the lambda expression. I watched an error log but there is not an issue it usually seems like the daily log. I am unable to troubleshoot and solve the issue. Can anyone tell me about this issue?

Comment: If your logs don't show the issue, then update your logs until the issue is visible in logs. Or try to reproduce the issue and localise the problem.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to start the instance? Have you added debugging code around it to show what might be failing? Are you able to manually start the RDS instance, just to check that it is possible?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sir, I have added the code.

Comment: FYI, you can access a function's environment variable via `import os` and 
`dbName = os.environ['DBInstanceName'])`

Comment: Instead of `return response`, can you `print response`? That way, you'll see the result in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, a shortened version would be:

```py
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
    response = rds.start_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier=os.environ['DBInstanceName'])
    print response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the logs of each lambda calls in cloudwatch or in aws lambda-> monitoring -> view logs in cloud watch. This will open a page with logs of each lambda call. 
if there is not logs. it means that lambda is not invoking. 
you can check the roles and policies assign to lambda if that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, sir. As I have mentioned in the question that I checked the log and it seems like a daily log (Watched from the same path as you described).But unable to reach the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should print the response of the api you use to start the db (ex- start-db-instance). The response will be printed to CloudWatch Log.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/start-db-instance.html

for later automation you might want to create a metric-filter on the Lambda's CloudWatch Logs on a certain keyword such as -

"\"DBInstanceStatus\": \"starting\""

there will be an Alarm created as well with setting say threshold < 1, and if the keyword is not found in a log the metric will push no Value (you can customize this setting under Advanced option) and the Alarm will go in to INSUFFICIENT_DATA and you can set notification for INSUFFICIENT_DATA using SNS.

You can tweak the Alarm a bit to treat missing data as Bad and then Alarm will transition to ALARM state when metric filter does not match with the incoming log.